# Underline fixed in input text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, input, underline

I'm trying to fixed the underline in all input text type, but without success.

Example:

[image]

My code:

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <label for="endereco">Endereço:</label>
  <input class="" id="endereco" type="text" tabindex="2" minlength="5" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: yes!!! I tried everything and not such effect

Answer (score 8):

Use `linear-gradient` as background to create a line and you can easily control its size and position like this:

```css
input {
  width: 300px;
  background: 
      linear-gradient(#000, #000) center bottom 5px /calc(100% - 10px) 2px no-repeat;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input class="" id="endereco" type="text" tabindex="2" minlength="5" required>
```

Using the longhand syntax:

```css
input {
  width: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  background-position: bottom 5px center;
  background-size: calc(100% - 10px) 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input class="" id="endereco" type="text" tabindex="2" minlength="5" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a border to the bottom of the input?

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <label for="endereco">Endereço:</label>
  <input class="" id="endereco" type="text" tabindex="2" minlength="5" required>
</div>
```

Comment: If you take a look in the image, is not border-bottom. The line doesn't touch the border-left and border-right.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You want the line not to touch the left and right borders? So you want it to be less than 100% width?

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```css
.custom-input{
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px;
    border-color: #DADADA;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #323A47;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="12" class="custom-input">
```