# How to draw a vertical line inside an input field?

Tags: css, input, styles

This is a picture of what I need to do:

[image]

This is my input

```
  <input type='text'
    id='c-start-retro-form-retroname'
    className='u-margin-bottom-tiny u-margin-top-tiny u-1/1'
    placeholder={'Retrosopective name'}
    onChange={this.handleRetrospectiveNameChange}>
  <i className='fa fa-folder'></i>
```

But the icon of the folder is left outside the input. How can I put a vertical line and the icon of the folder inside?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you can get an idea here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270694/underline-fixed-in-input-text/48270841#48270841 using linear gradient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these styles:

```
i.fa-folder {
  transform: translatex(calc(-100%)); /* move left the icon's width */
  border-left: 1px solid black;       /* add the border             */
  padding: 0 7px;                     /* left and right padding     */
}

input {
  padding-right: 2em;                 /* prevent typing over icon   */
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
i.fa-folder-open {
  transform: translatex(calc(-100%)); /* move left the icon's width */
  border-left: 1px solid black;       /* add the border             */
  padding: 0 7px;                     /* left and right padding     */
}

input {
  padding-right: 2em;                 /* prevent typing over icon   */
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <input
    type='text'
    id='c-start-retro-form-retroname'
    className='u-margin-bottom-tiny u-margin-top-tiny u-1/1'
    placeholder='Retrosopective name'
  />
  <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

These components are typically created by combining numerous HTML elements in such a way that allows for more complex presentations. The input box in that image is likely created by combining multiple `div`s, `input`, `img`, and possibly other carefully stylized elements.

There are various libraries that help you create components like that. Check out [**Semantic UI**](https://semantic-ui.com/) for example. Look at the list of their [**input components**](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/input.html) and you'll find various styles resembling what you have in mind. This one looks close:

[image: Semantic UI input element]

---

As a side note, if you are ever curious about how a certain website has implemented their components, the best way to figure out what they've done is to use your browser's **Developer Tools** to inspect the elements and review the hierarchy and styles of elements combined together.

For example, if you use Chrome, right click on any component on your web page, click on **Inspect**, and you'll be presented with the HTML and CSS code of that component and all the elements that are nested within it. For example, that Semantic UI input component that I've suggested above is created using an enclosing `div`, and an `input` and another `div` nested within it:

[image: Use your browser's Developer Tools to see how UI elements are built and styled]